# how to add a google recaptcha to sign-in form in the frontend

Tags: google-recaptcha

i am using Magento 2.2 , in terms of security i want to add a Google reCAPTCHA to sign-in form for the customers to create their accounts , so i need to add google reCAPTCHA to this form to check if they are robots or a humans.

> can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of resources that might help you with this. I'll add the links below:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-add-google-recaptcha-into-magento-2.html

If you take a look at these. The Mageplaza one in particular has some good advice.

Essentially, you would have to create some Google recaptcha API's here:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Install the Google reCaptcha extension (a free one can be found at the below link):

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/

and then configure it in **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Security > Google reCaptcha**

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Stores > Configuration > Security > Google reCaptcha** give cridentials to general tab field, enable frontend and you will see option to show it in forms.

[image]

Comment: why i can't see the 'security' section ?

Comment: It should be under Catalog. Please check properly

Comment: which version of Magento you have?

Comment: In older Magento versions, you need to install module `msp/recaptcha`. In recent Magento it was incorporated into core Magento

Answer (score 1):

try adding this extension. [LINK](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/)

Magento 2.2.x does not have a Security section in the config area

Happy Coding